# Where did all my Jenkins configurations disappear?

Tags: jenkins

I have been running Jenkins on Apache Tomcat for a few months. I then killed the process so I could deploy it on another port. I did so and restarted Jenkins, only to see that my startup screen was empty, no jobs :) I then re-set the port back to 8080 and restarted Tomcat, but the screen is still empty. All downloaded plugins are at zero. What just happened and how can I retrieve my settings?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was just because I restarted it as another user :)